# How to convert this Simple SQLServer statement into MySQL statement?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Given a table that has 3 columns: C1, C2, C3

```
C1 - C2 - C3
M  - is - M1
N2 - is - N3
M2 - is - M3
M3 - is - M4
N1 - is - N2
M1 - is - M2
N  - is - N1
```

How to convert this Simple SQLServer statement into MySQL statement:

```
declare @searchString varchar(32) = 'M';
with cte(results) as
(
    select C3 from Tbl where C1 = @searchString
    union all
    select t.C3 from Tbl t inner join cte c on c.C3 = t.C1 
) select * from cte;
```

Comment: This is a recursive CTE.  There is no easy way to convert this to MySQL.

Comment: ok, then how to write stored procedure in MySQL for the above query